# How do you get an ADBannerView's rendered width in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, iad, adbannerview

I'm trying to get the rendered width of an ADBannerView but it always seems to be the same as my UIScreen's mainScreen's width:

```
adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
[self.navController.view addSubview:adBannerView];
NSLog(@"Banner's width: %f.", adBannerView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"Screen's width: %f.", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
```

The two logs above show the same value. I want to eventually center my banner horizontally using the code below, but the width I get back from the banner's frame needs to be the rendered width:

```
adBannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(adBannerView.frame, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - adBannerView.frame.size.width)/2.0f, 0);
```

So how do I get the rendered width of the ADBannerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to share a solution that worked for me. It looks like all my problems were due to my usage of Cocos2D. I shouldn't of used `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width`. Here is what worked for me to properly, and finally, center the ad from my application's delegate (which inherits CCAppDelegate, so its like I was trying to mix-and-match two different interface sizing methodologies):

```
adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
adBannerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
CGSize sizeToFit = [adBannerView sizeThatFits:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].frame.size];
// It is assumed that sizeThatFits returns size with a width smaller than the director's width, so just see if it needs to be centered.
[adBannerView setFrame:CGRectMake(([[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].frame.size.width - sizeToFit.width)/2.0f, 0, sizeToFit.width, sizeToFit.height)];
adBannerView.delegate = self;
[self.navController.view addSubview:adBannerView];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these sizes for bannerView:

```
extern NSString * const ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
extern NSString * const ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
extern NSString * const ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
extern NSString * const ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
```

But there is another scope:

> To resize a banner view, use sizeThatFits: on the banner view,
>   specifying the bounds of the view that contains the banner view.
>   Resize the banner view with the returned size. The banner view will be
>   sized to the correct width and height of the current device and
>   orientation. The following code snippet shows a possible
>   implementation:

```
ADBannerView *myBannerView = <#Get a banner view#>;
UIView *myContainingView = <#Get the containing view#>;
NSSize newBannerSize = [myBannerView sizeThatFits:myContainingView];
[myBannerView setBounds:newBannerSize];
```

If you just want to center your BannerView:

```
adBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - adBannerView.frame.size.width)/2,adBannerView.frame.origin.y,adBannerView.frame.size.width,adBannerView.frame.size.height);
```

I hope it helps.

[Documentation about ADBannerView is available here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: No, this won't work. Setting the frame is not going to center it properly. When the ad comes in, it takes on a specific size. That's exactly what I'm trying to do above with CGRectOffset but describing how it doesn't work. Also, using the hardcoded sizes is deprecated which is why I targeted this question for iOS 7, so I don't really want to go down the road of using that option. Also, setBounds takes a CGRect, not an NSSize.

Comment: Also, even using sizeThatFits returns back the same value as [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width. Thus, going back to the problem of trying to center it again because the ad that is displayed does not take up the entire screen's width!

Comment: Looks like the reason why it wasn't working for me all this time is because my application delegate is inheriting the CCAppDelegate since I'm using Cocos2D and I wasn't comparing my app's width against the director's width.

Comment: This was deprecated in iOS 6, but Apple provided no alternative!